# Issue with json encode of database string value

Tags: php, json, decode, encode

I have database query result in php array as below:

```
Array
(
    [status] => 1
    [message] => Successfully Login
    [request] => Array
        (
            [firstName] => Jugni
            [lastName] => Patel
            [popup_message] => To login to this portal you have to agree out terms and condition
• L80 – R169 pm x 24 on SMARTCHAT 1GB
• G3 Beat – R259 pm x 24 on SMARTCHAT 1GB
• G3 – R399 pm x 24 on SMARTCHAT 1GB
Top 5 MTN Sales consultants for period 2-8 March 2015, on G3 & G3 Beat sales will WIN R500 each! You have until Monday 9 March 9AM to log your sales for this competition!
        )

)
```

When i am doing json_encode of above array then it is giving null value in description.

```
{"status":"1","message":"Successfully Login","request":{"firstName":"Jugni","lastName":"Patel","popup_message":null}}
```

**Update:**

Now i am able to get the value of description using utf8_encode method.
But when i am again decoding that string using json_decode then it is giving below output:

It giving decode value as below:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 1
    [message] => Successfully Login
    [request] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstName] => Jugni
            [lastName] => Patel
            [popup_message] => To login to this portal you have to agree out terms and condition
Â• L80 Â– R169 pm x 24 on SMARTCHAT 1GB
Â• G3 Beat Â– R259 pm x 24 on SMARTCHAT 1GB
Â• G3 Â– R399 pm x 24 on SMARTCHAT 1GB
Top 5 MTN Sales consultants for period 2-8 March 2015, on G3 & G3 Beat sales will WIN R500 each! You have until Monday 9 March 9AM to log your sales for this competition!
        )

)
```

Does anybody know how can i get same value of description field after json_encode?

Comment: How do you create the php array? Can you post the piece of code where you add the 'popup_message' in it?

Comment: $result=array('status'=> '1',"message"=>"Successfully Login","request"=>array("firstName"=>$row['Name'],"lastName"=>$row['Surname'],"popup_message"=>($row['Description'])));
  }
print_r(json_encode($result));

Comment: I see your edited answer, you get this data because the page where you print the result is not encoded in UTF-8. Put `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` on top of your page outside the php tag.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the string in your array is `utf8`-encoded. [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) requires `utf8`-encoded strings and will return `false` on faliure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Its working but facing issue while decode that encoded string using utf8_encode method.

Comment: You have to use `utf8_decode` to decode the utf8-encoded string.